# Icons in tabbar are not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, ipad, tabbar

I have an issue with iPad application. I'm porting the iPhone app to iPad. In iPhone, all is working in order but when convert to iPad (Universal app),  the tabbar controller looks like this

[image]

(vertical lines) Do you guys have any ideas why?

Thanks for any comments or guides.

Comment: are you using a custom tab bar ?Seems like there is a image in the tab bar's background that seems not to fit in iPad correctly.

Comment: Some code would make it more easy for us to check the problem, and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be in default TabBar. I am sure you are using custom tabbar and its layout are not managing properly in iPad.

So make some adjustment in your custom tabbar and then use it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Found it. Some one use the fixed image for tabbar appearance. Thanks.

Comment: UITabBar *tabBarAppearance = [UITabBar appearance];
    tabBarAppearance.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar"];
    tabBarAppearance.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_highlight"];

Answer (score 0):

Try to check autosizing mask (or autolayout) if you use them.

Then try to check if you change its frame (it could disable autosizing).

It also seems you want to draw these separators manually but tab bar appearance depends on iOS version. At general I advice you to use custom images to a whole tab bar, not its items.

Comment: To clarify this some more: draw the pressed button state by providing `UITabBar`'s `selectionIndicatorImage`, not along with the `UITabBarItem`'s selected image. Make this image resizable (`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`) and it should work with both Pad and Phone idioms and all tab bar widths.

Comment: As I understand he needs custom separators too

Comment: So make the separator a part of the background.